# Android - setting data in views of a fragment based on an async server response

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments, android-asynctask, android-lifecycle

I have the following fragment as below, wherein the onPostNetworkRequestWithCode() method is called back by another part of the code (the App extends Application class which does network requests), to paint the views

Since the fragment creation chain (onCreate(), onCreateView() etc) are called in a different thread than the onPostNetworkRequestWithCode() which repaints the views, I am having a race condition sometimes when the onPostNetworkRequestWithCode() method does not find a view to paint. How can I ask it to wait till the view creation is done and then resume post that?

```
public class MeStatsTableFragment extends Fragment implements HttpResponseHandlerWithResponseCode {

    private static final String LINKED_USER_ID = "linkedUserId";
    private Context mContext;

    public MeStatsTableFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    public static MeStatsTableFragment newInstance(long linkedUserId, Context context) {
        MeStatsTableFragment fragment = new MeStatsTableFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putLong(LINKED_USER_ID, linkedUserId);

        fragment.setArguments(args);
        fragment.mContext = context;
        return fragment;
    }


    /**
     * This is responsible for painting the chart after data is obtained by parent Me Fragment
     */
    @Override
    public void onPostNetworkRequestWithCode(HttpResponseCode responseCode) {

        long linkedUserId = getArguments().getLong(LINKED_USER_ID);
        MePageInfo m = App.getAppData().getMePageInfoById(linkedUserId);


        View v = getView();

        if (v == null) {
            Log.d("XXX", "Stats fragment Got stuck at view == null in Stats Fragment");
            // do nothing else, just return
        } else{


            v.findViewById(R.id.text_name).setText(m.name);
            // do other painting similarly with the view and the variable m



    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_me_stats_table, container, false);
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }


}
```

Comment: Where is this painting being done?  Is there another view that displays the other data?

Comment: You can make this with a boolean variable . set the boolean variable true if the view is null inside the callback and check the variable in onresume then if the variable is true you can set the text to the textview and reset the variable .

Answer (score 0):

You could use greenrobot EventBus (https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) - and make a sticky post, in a case when there is no fragment yet.

Here is more info about sticky post and register - https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus/blob/master/HOWTO.md#sticky-events

Comment: Is there a way of doing this without using EventBus?

Comment: In your case you could make this - MePageInfo m into field, and check if it is null in onViewCreated(...), if it is not do your manipulations, but if it is null still, that means that getView() is not going to be null when MePageInfo m is not null.